# Tenses of supposition?

Tags: tenses

Could anyone tell me the tense of these sentences?

1. I should have done my homework by now.
2. Had he cooked a risotto, he would have won the contest.

As far as I can remember, in school, we classified the first sentence as present perfect tense of supposition.

Could anyone clarify the tenses of those sentences?

Comment: I would be grateful if someone answered this instead of downvoting.

Comment: Modal usages have been covered here in many different threads. Have you looked at any of them? The person downvoting was probably concerned that the site's requirement for checking for similar questions didn't seem to have been considered important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why there isn't a simple answer is because the question is wrong.
There are too many false assumptions, and one gets tired of correcting them.

First, ***tense*** has nothing to do  with these constructions; there are only two inflected tenses in English (Present and Past), and multiplying named tenses, [while a lot of fun](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html#tenselist), explains nothing whatsoever.

Second, the first sentence does not have any tense at all, since *should* is a modal auxiliary verb and modal auxiliary verbs do not inflect for tense. The second sentence has two clauses, with two verbs: *Had* and *would*; the first is Past tense, and the second is another modal auxiliary verb.

Third, if you really want to call the modals formed on preterite stems (*would, could, should, might, must*) Past tense, you have to call the others (*will, can, shall, may*) Present tense. Of course that means that the Future tense is the Present tense, which is maybe a little confusing to some. And you have to say they're all defective verbs, because none of them have infinitive or participial forms -- only one Past form (which usually doesn't mean past time) and one Present form (except for *must*, which only appears in the Past tense, even though it usually refers to the future).

Fourth, any tense can be used to mark hypothetical or counterfactual clauses, referring to past, present, or future -- that isn't English tense, it's constructions of various sorts, which sometimes have tenses and sometimes don't.

So, while the terminology you learned in school probably made sense to your teacher and/or to the author of your textbook, it's not a matter of "tense", and there are no standard terms for it that exhaust the possibilities. It's a matter of idiomatic modal constructions, of which there are dozens if not hundreds.